# .Net MAUI MainPage on ShellContent appears in every page

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I have my MainPage defined in the shellContent this way:
`

```
    <Shell
        x:Class="AuPairFind.AppShell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AuPairFind"
        Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:AuPairFind.View">
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:MainPage}"
            Route="MainPage" />
    </Shell>
```

The problem is when i do the routing to another page the MainPage continues on the new page just like in the image below:

[image: MainPage ghost appearing]

How can i stop the MainPage from showing in every page?

I've tried changing the shellContent page and the problem persists

**Solved:**
Using verticalStackLayout with ignoreSafeArea="True" solved my problem

Comment: I did a test, but I couldn't reproduce this problem. Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can test on our side?